# Natural sentence about line (waiting)

Tags: words

I couldn't confirm if these are correct/natural ways to say these...

1. 待ち行列 : waiting line (queue)
2. 行列を待っています : (I'm currently) waiting in the line (queue)
3. 行列を待ってください : Please wait in the line
4. 行列を作って並んでください : Please make a line and then line up

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 3):

1 and 4 are correct, but 待ち行列 looks like a technical term of [queueing theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory). Usually saying 行列 is enough.

～を待つ is "to wait *for* ～". Therefore 行列を待っています would mean "I am waiting for the line," which is not what you usually want to say.

To say "to wait *in* the line", the particle you need is, unsurprisingly, で.

2. 行列で待っています。
3. 行列でお待ちください。 (using the honorific version of 待つ)

Comment: could we use に too as in 行列に待っています ? :)

Comment: No you can't. Don't ask me why :)